# How to upload a multiple files using Storage Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Now I use a simple way to upload images:

```
if ($request->hasFile("images")) {
   $file = $request->file("images");

  // Do uploading to Storage
  $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath. $fileName, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
```

How can I upload multiple files when I have: `images[]` in HTML form?
Is it possible to do with `Storage::put()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view (using the LaravelCollective package):

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'MyController@store', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]) }}
{{ Form::file('attachments[]', ['class' => 'form-control', 'roles' => 'form', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (($request->has('attachments'))) {
         $files = $request->file('attachments');

         $destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/public/';
         foreach ($files as $file) {
             $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
             $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $storeName = $fileName . '.' . $extension;
             // Store the file in the disk 
             $file->move($destinationPath, $storeName);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: It does not work, this conditional is false: `if (($request->has('attachments')))` May be it should be: ` if (($request->has('files'))) {`

Comment: @Putin I haven't checked my code, because it is an adaptation from an existent code, but $request->has('attachments') is correct. You have an attachments[] element in the view.

Answer (score 4):

If your form is submitting multiple files under images[] array, you would loop through them accordingly.

It would help if you posted the form html as well.

```
<?php
    $files = $request->file("images");
    $uploaded = [];
    if($files){
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $uploaded[] = Storage::put($destinationPath. $fileName, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
        }
    }
});
```